# Substitution of the date in an additional column

Tags: r, date, dplyr

Sample dataset

```
df <- data.frame(
  x1 = c("17.10.2022", "Godzina", "00:00 - 01:00", "01:00 - 02:00", "02:00 - 03:00", "03:00 - 04:00", "04:00 - 05:00", "05:00 - 06:00", "06:00 - 07:00"),
  x2 = c(NA, NA, 17.09497, 17.29869, 17.34341, 17.10647, 17.10647, 17.01680, 17.18461)
  )
```

I would like the end result to be as follows

```
             x1       x2         x3
1 00:00 - 01:00 17.09497 17.10.2022
2 01:00 - 02:00 17.29869 17.10.2022
3 02:00 - 03:00 17.34341 17.10.2022
4 03:00 - 04:00 17.10647 17.10.2022
5 04:00 - 05:00 17.10647 17.10.2022
6 05:00 - 06:00 17.01680 17.10.2022
7 06:00 - 07:00 17.18461 17.10.2022
```

There are about a thousand such tables, and I would like to do it elegantly and efficiently.

Comment: `df <- df[-c(1:2),]` then `df[,3] <- "17.10.2022"` will recreate your desired output, but you have provided insufficient information to know if that will really help you. I suggest you try to provide more clarity. For instance, if all tables are all in the same structure and you always want to pull the date from the first row, first column - you could do: `df[,3] <- df[1,1]` then `df <- df[-c(1:2),]` - in this case both approaches give you the same output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all tables are shaped like the example this might help

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(x3 = x1[1]) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  summarize(x1, x2 = x2[!is.na(x2)], x3)
# A tibble: 7 × 3
  x1               x2 x3
  <chr>         <dbl> <chr>
1 00:00 - 01:00  17.1 17.10.2022
2 01:00 - 02:00  17.3 17.10.2022
3 02:00 - 03:00  17.3 17.10.2022
4 03:00 - 04:00  17.1 17.10.2022
5 04:00 - 05:00  17.1 17.10.2022
6 05:00 - 06:00  17.0 17.10.2022
7 06:00 - 07:00  17.2 17.10.2022
```